# Labels with targets to another view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I would like to have a login similar to [this screenshot](http://goo.gl/KUA74):

[image: Screenshot]

The problem is that I don't know how to do the bottom, these two options. When I push, I'd like to put another view — the sign up view or reset password view —, but I don't know how to do these elements (are they labels?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They could be `UIButton` with the type Custom and with a value for the text:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To make this, First you take a `UILabel` to show the "Tumblr" option. Then you create a `UITableView`. This TableView would contain 2 sections like "Email" and "Password". Make the edges of the UITableView as rounded using

`TableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;`

Now to push to another view you can simply write any data in the `UITableViewCells` in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and using the

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

you can pass that information to the next view for the reset password option you mentioned likewise. Create a `UIButton` and name it as "Login".

I this is what you wanted to achieve ?? Any doubts please tell. Thanks :)

**EDIT:**

For the options below what you can do is that make the `UIButtons` as *custom* and write their text as "Reset Password" etc. Then on their click you can open a presentModalViewController of each of the next view's or in the same view itself, in which you would be able to do your sign in and reset stuff. Hope it helps !!!

Comment: Thank you. That helps me for the first part, the bottom, the two options "Sign up" and "Reset". I want to do that, and, when I push them, a viewcontroller created by me appears. I'll try the other answers and lets see the result. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for both answers ;)

Comment: @Juanjo how did u do it ?? Using the Xib file ?? Did my post really help you ?

Comment: Yes, I put both buttons and the style "Custom"(I didn`t know that with that style the button looks that mode), and both with their IBActions :)

Answer (score 1):

It is a label and you link it with the action method.

Answer (score 1):

```
//using   UITapGestureRecognizer to easy to set target to another view

 UITapGestureRecognizer *tab_1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(action_1)];
    tab_1.delegate = self;
    [label1 addGestureRecognizer: tab_1];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tab_2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(action_2)];
    tab_2.delegate = self;
    [label2 addGestureRecognizer: tab_2];

    -(void)action_1{
    //your action or view;
    }

    -(void)action_2{
    //your action or view;
    }
```